# Renaming Android app package causes gradle crash

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to change the package name of my app but I'm seeing this gradle crash when building.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':main:MyApp:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>   /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt package -f --no-crunch -I /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar -M /Users//Documents/workspace/android/application/main/MyApp/build/manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S /Users//Documents/workspace/android/application/main/MyApp/build/res/all/debug -A /Users//Documents/workspace/android/application/main/MyApp/build/assets/debug -m -J /Users//Documents/workspace/android/application/main/MyApp/build/source/r/debug -F /Users//Documents/workspace/android/application/main/MyApp/build/libs/MyApp-debug.ap_ -G /Users//Documents/workspace/android/application/main/MyApp/build/proguard/debug/aapt_rules.txt --debug-mode --custom-package com.app.myapp --output-text-symbols /Users//Documents/workspace/android/application/main/MyApp/build/symbols/debug
>   Error Code:
>   138

Comment: Could you post your "build.gradle" file and your application manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to change package name is

1) Go to manifest click on `package="packagename"` and press Shift+F6. Do refactor with all changes in all .

2) Click `Do refactor` in build config if that turns up

3) Go to package in src/main/java

4) `Right click -> refactor -> move` and click move to another package. Choose name and target directory.

5) It will create new package with files.

6) Delete old empty package

7) Clean project, restart android studio and clean once again

8) If you go to `build/generated/source/r/debug` you will see package name has changed.